# Pointer Lock API entry is giving a large number when window is squished why?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm putting two screenshots to show whats going on:

The fullscreen one works fine - as soon as I click on my canvas element and the mouse locks it is frozen still until I actually put some movement in.

The other screenshot shows the problem. When I have the browser resized to different amounts it causes the movementX to be at a non-zero value it stays closer to zero the less squished the window is. (it's not -965 if I have it scaled different but it's always -965 if I have it docked to the side of my screen).

---

[image: First image]
First image (working correctly): https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0pO0.png

[image: Second image]
Second image (not working correctly): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vioew.png

See how I have turned to the side due to the -965 movementX value on entry. Why has this happened and how can I prevent it? / I want it to not move on entry no matter where the camera is looking.

Comment: Could you include your pointer-lock code (as text, not in a screenshot)?

Comment: I've put all files i'm using into a github folder. https://github.com/Wuzzie/wuzzie/tree/master/examples

Comment: @WestLangley isn't this a webgl problem? HTML5 rocks has examples on their pointer lock api tutorial which has the exact same problem as I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a look at the code, and I can only reproduce the issue in Chrome (it's fine in Firefox, IE11 doesn't support pointer lock). It would seem to be related to the event handlers being on the document rather than the canvas, yet only as a Chrome/Webkit specific bug.

I've been able to work around the problem by ignoring the large initial value:

```
    console.log("Logging (movementX, movementY): (", movementX, ", ", movementY, ")");
    if ( movementX < -10 || movementY < -10 ) {
        return;
    }
```

You may need to tweak the number, it was just a quick test.

Comment: Hi thanks for this it although I'm still wondering why it happens a fix is greatly appreciated. :) I'm going to put it around -300 because the bug ranged from -400 to -965.